# Keycloak - 401 response (USER_INFO_REQUEST_ERROR) when obtaining userinfo via /realms/{realm}/protocol/openid-connect/userinfo

Tags: keycloak

I have a Keycloak deployed locally with the following Docker command:

> docker run -p 8080:8080 -e KEYCLOAK_ADMIN=admin -e
> KEYCLOAK_ADMIN_PASSWORD=admin quay.io/keycloak/keycloak:20.0.1
> start-dev

I get a token from Keycloak. Example:

> eyJhbGciOiJSUzI1NiIsInR5cCIgOiAiSldUIiwia2lkIiA6ICJMZjRfWHJjWkpTaVJYWlFLS254VS1NdU9FTHA4d3NaaHlLMDQ0UjRIRjdnIn0.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.j_rFqVxICtj7NR-myEsWhSkwBeCABplFrmlBuRMAhF4N8HzdOOtExdmw_mXdx60snKTaE5GJHPofjllpM353lY8H9NGxaczUgL20GjVmMhwtihGGBLpiw7TXyGQGkfdBXdweCuS0W1avegXrhRYvCYlFGJMoxsdmskYkDt4DjuESlTkMEOndVjv5LBp3rLB6lRopq0Qg3Abp_rv57KvlVeeul24OKoisFohnZ4VfsiDPAuVW1u1xaYmjCRDlBwIcGosdwasL_WNAgvJkaKdVtvu7NU-ghPa1vQkWJkMZrVIZDsCc5LKZqwspw3U2iOcUc5EDC6FumBWdfvWCx8cszw

Its payload:

```
{
  "exp": 1670087508,
  "iat": 1670087208,
  "auth_time": 1670086470,
  "jti": "2ad1849d-1224-48b6-afcc-5fac1fc867f4",
  "iss": "http://localhost:8080/realms/dialog-feat",
  "aud": "account",
  "sub": "4db7b685-4da0-4fc3-b625-82fc517c6076",
  "typ": "Bearer",
  "azp": "somex5",
  "nonce": "GKMoRVE5Cj6RV2LpT5289yT7EGVxS3fN",
  "session_state": "168cbfdd-2afa-4299-b8be-2a13ac22672b",
  "acr": "0",
  "realm_access": {
    "roles": [
      "offline_access",
      "uma_authorization",
      "default-roles-dialog-feat"
    ]
  },
  "resource_access": {
    "account": {
      "roles": [
        "manage-account",
        "manage-account-links",
        "view-profile"
      ]
    }
  },
  "scope": "openid profile email",
  "sid": "168cbfdd-2afa-4299-b8be-2a13ac22672b",
  "email_verified": true,
  "name": "John Snow",
  "preferred_username": "john.snow",
  "given_name": "John",
  "family_name": "Snow",
  "email": "john.snow@x5.ru"
}
```

It seems valid. Then I'm making a request to `http://127.0.0.1:8080/realms/dialog-feat/protocol/openid-connect/userinfo` with the token:

> curl --location --request GET
> 'http://127.0.0.1:8080/realms/dialog-feat/protocol/openid-connect/userinfo'
>
> --header 'Authorization: Bearer eyJhbGciOiJSUzI1NiIsInR5cCIgOiAiSldUIiwia2lkIiA6ICJMZjRfWHJjWkpTaVJYWlFLS254VS1NdU9FTHA4d3NaaHlLMDQ0UjRIRjdnIn0.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.j_rFqVxICtj7NR-myEsWhSkwBeCABplFrmlBuRMAhF4N8HzdOOtExdmw_mXdx60snKTaE5GJHPofjllpM353lY8H9NGxaczUgL20GjVmMhwtihGGBLpiw7TXyGQGkfdBXdweCuS0W1avegXrhRYvCYlFGJMoxsdmskYkDt4DjuESlTkMEOndVjv5LBp3rLB6lRopq0Qg3Abp_rv57KvlVeeul24OKoisFohnZ4VfsiDPAuVW1u1xaYmjCRDlBwIcGosdwasL_WNAgvJkaKdVtvu7NU-ghPa1vQkWJkMZrVIZDsCc5LKZqwspw3U2iOcUc5EDC6FumBWdfvWCx8cszw'

But I get a 401 status code returned. For example:

```
type=USER_INFO_REQUEST_ERROR, realmId=(...), clientId=null, userId=null, ipAddress=(...), error=access_denied, auth_method=validate_access_token
```

How to fix this?

My Keycloak settings:

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem seems to be a mismatch between the issuer of the access token sent to the userinfo endpoint (*i.e.,* "iss": "http://localhost:8080/realms/dialog-feat") and the issuer that the access token validator triggered by the userinfo endpoint is expecting.

Instead of:

> Then I'm making a request to
> http://127.0.0.1:8080/realms/dialog-feat/protocol/openid-connect/userinfo
> with the token (...):

Use the same hostname in the userinfo endpoint has the one that you have used to acquire the access token, for instance:

```
curl http://localhost:8080/realms/dialog-feat/protocol/openid-connect/userinfo -H "Authorization: Bearer (..<your access token..)"
```

If the problem still persistes then you also facing the issues related with the Keycloak endpoint implementation described in [UserInfo endpoint not fully standards compliant](https://github.com/keycloak/keycloak/pull/14237).

In short in your request for a the access token explicitly add the parameter `scope=openid`. An example:

```
curl --request POST \
        --url "http://localhost:8080/realms/dialog-feat/protocol/openid-connect/token" \
        --data client_id=somex5 \
        --data username=john.snow \
        --data password=...<the password..> \
        --data grant_type=password \
        --data scope=openid
```

Comment: You're right. I changed 127.0.0.1 to localhost and it worked

Comment: That's problematic though, it's expected that the place to validate token - possibly in backend after the reverse proxy - use vastly different hostname than the one used by frontend.

Comment: @TamakiSakura Wouldn't setting the frontendURL fix that issue?

Comment: @dreamcrash you were sort of right - my version is 20.0.2. The "frontendURL" in my case is called `KC_HOSTNAME_URL`. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75327787/keycloak-20-0-2-does-not-accept-backchannel-connection