# Keycloak integration problem with JupyterHub

Tags: keycloak, jupyterhub

I've Keycloak deployed and run in k8s cluster with helm release.
There is a client 'styx' configured for JupyterHub in 'dev' realm.
The client has 'Client authentication' turned on.

When the correct username and password are entered and redirect happen from Keycloak back to JupyterHub it fails on retrieving user info (HTTP 403 error from Keycloak).

```
[E 2023-01-11 02:34:20.026 JupyterHub oauth2:386] Error fetching user data 403 GET https://ceres.themodelvault.com/realms/dev/protocol/openid-connect/userinfo:
[E 2023-01-11 02:34:20.027 JupyterHub web:1798] Uncaught exception GET /hub/oauth_callback?state=eyJzdGF0ZV9pZCI6ICIzZWZiZjQzNzM4ZDA0ZmM2YTZmODdjYzk4MDAxZjkxNCIsICJuZXh0X3VybCI6ICIvaHViLyJ9&session_state=129fa2d5-c9d3-4d13-8539-7611f0e05604&code=3d9031f9-3889-4ad4-a676-4d2276e5907f.129fa2d5-c9d3-4d13-8539-7611f0e05604.0526b372-e282-401f-af45-6ea2ca2647fd (::ffff:10.0.106.200)
    HTTPServerRequest(protocol='http', host='styx-dev.themodelvault.com', method='GET', uri='/hub/oauth_callback?state=eyJzdGF0ZV9pZCI6ICIzZWZiZjQzNzM4ZDA0ZmM2YTZmODdjYzk4MDAxZjkxNCIsICJuZXh0X3VybCI6ICIvaHViLyJ9&session_state=129fa2d5-c9d3-4d13-8539-7611f0e05604&code=3d9031f9-3889-4ad4-a676-4d2276e5907f.129fa2d5-c9d3-4d13-8539-7611f0e05604.0526b372-e282-401f-af45-6ea2ca2647fd', version='HTTP/1.1', remote_ip='::ffff:10.0.106.200')
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/tornado/web.py", line 1713, in _execute
        result = await result
      File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/oauthenticator/oauth2.py", line 222, in get
        user = await self.login_user()
      File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/jupyterhub/handlers/base.py", line 801, in login_user
        authenticated = await self.authenticate(data)
      File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/jupyterhub/auth.py", line 491, in get_authenticated_user
        authenticated = await maybe_future(self.authenticate(handler, data))
      File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/oauthenticator/generic.py", line 165, in authenticate
        user_data_resp_json = await self._get_user_data(token_resp_json)
      File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/oauthenticator/oauth2.py", line 387, in fetch
        raise e
      File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/oauthenticator/oauth2.py", line 366, in fetch
        resp = await self.http_client.fetch(req, **kwargs)
    tornado.httpclient.HTTPClientError: HTTP 403: Forbidden
```

UPD: Fixed with https://keycloak.discourse.group/t/issue-on-userinfo-endpoint-at-keycloak-20/18461

Comment: Which Keycloak version are you using

Comment: 20.0, and I found it needs to have openid scope for client as explained in https://keycloak.discourse.group/t/issue-on-userinfo-endpoint-at-keycloak-20/18461

Comment: Yep, that is exactly why I asked, did not wanted to write an answer without be sure first. I have seen this one before https://stackoverflow.com/a/74674130/1366871

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed with openid scope as explained in https://keycloak.discourse.group/t/issue-on-userinfo-endpoint-at-keycloak-20/18461

Comment: Btw, you don't need to do all those steps just "add scope=openid when you request the access token."