# Keycloak 20.0.2 does not accept backchannel connection

Tags: authentication, keycloak, haproxy

I am having some issue with having Keycloak 20.0.2 working for my web application.

---

I have my keycloak URL accessible at:

`https://example.com/white-graduation/keycloak/auth`

This is designed for backend application to work with keycloak. It fundamentally usse haproxy as a reverse proxy to connect the https address to my internal keycloak.

So far, all frontend login has been working, without any issue. I can also have access to the keycloak control console UI.

The internal keycloak address is at:

`http://loginservice:8080/white-graudation/keycloak/auth`

This is designed for backend application to work with keycloak.

However, the backend login is facing a 401 issue.

---

By experimenting with different curl call in the container that's running the backend, I found that:

`curl -I -X GET https://example.com/white-graduation/keycloak/auth/realms/shirasaki-academy/protocol/openid-connect/userinfo -H "Authorization: Bearer Example-Bearer-Token"`

This API call gives 200, but

`curl -I -X GET https://loginservice:8080/white-graduation/keycloak/auth/realms/shirasaki-academy/protocol/openid-connect/userinfo -H "Authorization: Bearer Example-Bearer-Token"`

This gives 401. i.e. back-channel didn't work.

I did an expansion of `Example-Bearer-Token`, it does show that the `iss` is indeed only `https://example.com/white-graduation/keycloak/auth/realms/shirasaki-academy`, because the backend still uses frontend to login. But it should still work.

---

My Keycloak 20.0.2's setting:

```
KEYCLOAK_ADMIN=admin
KEYCLOAK_ADMIN_PASSWORD=whatever
KC_HTTP_RELATIVE_PATH=/white-graduation/keycloak/auth
KC_HOSTNAME_ADMIN_URL=https://example.com/white-graduation/keycloak/auth
KC_HOSTNAME_STRICT=false
KC_HTTP_ENABLED=true
KC_HTTP_PORT=8080
KC_HOSTNAME_STRICT_HTTPS=false
KC_PROXY=edge
```

The Keycloak 20.0.2's Quarkus is run through:

```
/opt/keycloak/bin/kc.sh start-dev --import-realm --log-level=org.keycloak.events:debug --spi-login-protocol-openid-connect-legacy-logout-redirect-uri=true
```

Note that I did not set `KC_HOSTNAME_STRICT_BACKCHANNEL` but this is by default already `false`, which under such case should allow back-channel connection to work.

**Note that this isn't the recommended setting for production environment.** But this isn't a production environment after all.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Problem solved by setting:

```
KC_HOSTNAME_URL=https://example.com/white-graduation/keycloak/auth
```

which means, `KC_HOSTNAME_URL == KC_HOSTNAME_ADMIN_URL`

After such, the internal API point starts working.

Not really sure why...but at least this solves my problem.

Comment: In my case, only base URL was required ("https://example.com").

In any case, have you found another way instead of declaring the hostname URL? Thanks!

Comment: No, but the non-base URL part in my case is precisely `KC_HTTP_RELATIVE_PATH`, I don't know if you can make that explicitly empty though, as I never tired that, but at least it looked promising.